# PHP XML encoding error - using XMLWriter

Tags: php, xml, laravel, encoding, xmlwriter

I tried to find solution but I can't. I'm working on Laravel and I'm trying to create dynamic XML document. I'm using `XMLWriter`. My method in controller:

```
public function feed_xml() {
    header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
    $sql = "SELECT ic.id, i.description, c.name, ca.name as category_name, i.tags,
                i.image_folder, i.image, i.price 
                FROM msrd.item i, msrd.collection c, msrd.category ca, msrd.item_collection ic 
                WHERE i.active = 't' AND i.collection_id = c.id AND ca.id = i.category_id AND ic.item_id = i.id AND ic.original = true";
    $data = \DB::connection('test-connection')->select($sql);
    $seo_array = \Config::get('engine.seo_keywords');

    $xml = new \XMLWriter;
    $xml->openUri('php://output');
    $xml->setIndent(true); //debug only
    $xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml->startElement('feed');
    $xml->startAttribute('xmlns');
    $xml->text('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
    $xml->endAttribute();
    $xml->startAttribute('xmlns:g');
    $xml->text('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
    $xml->endAttribute();
    $xml->startElement('title');
    $xml->text('MySite');
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->startElement('link');
    $xml->writeAttribute('rel', 'self');
    $xml->writeAttribute('href', "http://exampl/feed.xml");
    $xml->endElement();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $xml->startElement('entry');
        $xml->startElement('g:id');
        $xml->text($row->id);
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->startElement('g:title');
        $xml->writeCData(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $this->utf8_tohtml($this->utf8_bad_replace(trim(substr($row->category_name, 0, 100))))));
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->writeElement('g:availability', 'in stock');
        $xml->startElement('g:description');
        $xml->writeCData(ucfirst(strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $this->utf8_tohtml($this->utf8_bad_replace(trim(substr($row->description, 0, 500))))))));
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->startElement('g:link');
        $seo_text = $seo_array[($row->id % sizeof($seo_array))];
        $xml->writeCData('http://example.com/subpage/' . $row->id . '/' . str_replace(" ", "-", trim(strtolower($seo_text . ' ' . $row->category_name . ' ' . $row->tags))));
        $xml->endElement();
        $xml->writeElement('g:image_link', 'http://example.com/common/fb_img_output.php?item_collection_id=' . $row->id . '&visual_id=3&image_width=1200&image_height=628&container_width=1200&container_height=628&image_folder=' . $row->image_folder . '&image=' . $row->image);
        $xml->writeElement('g:condition', 'new');
        $xml->writeElement('g:brand', 'MySite');
        $xml->writeElement('g:price', $row->price . ' USD');
        $xml->writeElement('g:google_product_category', 'Product Category');
        $xml->endElement();
    }

    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->endDocument();
}
```

My help functions:

```
private function utf8_tohtml($str) {
    $ret = '';
    $max = strlen($str);
    $last = 0;  // keeps the index of the last regular character
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $c = $str{$i};
        $c1 = ord($c);
        if ($c1 >> 5 == 6) {  // 110x xxxx, 110 prefix for 2 bytes unicode
            $ret .= substr($str, $last, $i - $last); // append all the regular characters we've passed
            $c1 &= 31; // remove the 3 bit two bytes prefix
            $c2 = ord($str{ ++$i}); // the next byte
            $c2 &= 63;  // remove the 2 bit trailing byte prefix
            $c2 |= (($c1 & 3) << 6); // last 2 bits of c1 become first 2 of c2
            $c1 >>= 2; // c1 shifts 2 to the right
            $ret .= '&#' . ($c1 * 100 + $c2) . ';'; // this is the fastest string concatenation
            $last = $i + 1;
        }
    }
    return $ret . substr($str, $last, $i); // append the last batch of regular characters
}

private function utf8_bad_replace($str, $replace = '') {
    $UTF8_BAD = '([\x00-\x7F]' . # ASCII (including control chars)
            '|[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]' . # non-overlong 2-byte
            '|\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]' . # excluding overlongs
            '|[\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}' . # straight 3-byte
            '|\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]' . # excluding surrogates
            '|\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}' . # planes 1-3
            '|[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}' . # planes 4-15
            '|\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}' . # plane 16
            '|(.{1}))';                              # invalid byte
    ob_start();
    while (preg_match('/' . $UTF8_BAD . '/S', $str, $matches)) {
        if (!isset($matches[2])) {
            echo $matches[0];
        } else {
            echo $replace;
        }
        $str = substr($str, strlen($matches[0]));
    }
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
}
```

I can't do anything. I'm trying to use `return \Response::make($xml, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');` but it's not working fine. I don't know what I need to do, my generator not working and shows next error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Remove the headers, so you can see results. Then, give us input here.

Comment: @MrD I find solution - I needed change charset in `header()` to `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: If **ISO-8859-1** is the solution, don't write *UTF-8* into the document: `$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');` - Also please post only a minimal example that contains enough code to reproduce your problem. Not just all code you experienced the problem first and you then wanted to ask about.  My suggestion is to always create a new example from scratch with as little code and data as necessary to reproduce the problem (isolation of the problem).

Comment: It's not my database, it's base in my job so I can't give you their content :< Only can I say it's XML parser giving error on next letters: `ç`, `è`, `é` and more like this.